# Is there any equivalent in terraform to the gcloud compute instances create-with-container command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

I am trying to create an VM in Google Compute Engine which automatically runs a container that I uploaded to the Google Container Registry (as described here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#how_deploying_containers_on_works)

The

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container [INSTANCE_NAME] \
     --container-image [DOCKER_IMAGE]
```

works so far, but I dont see any equivalent in Terraform.
From what I've seen google_compute_image is not what helps me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) to reverse-terraform my compute engine instance `instance-container` that runs Nginx container.

Here's the result terraform file

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "tfer--instance-002D-container" {
  boot_disk {
    auto_delete = "true"
    device_name = "instance-container"

    initialize_params {
      image = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cos-cloud/global/images/cos-stable-80-12739-91-0"
      size  = "10"
      type  = "pd-standard"
    }

    mode   = "READ_WRITE"
    source = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-id/zones/asia-east1-b/disks/instance-container"
  }

  can_ip_forward      = "false"
  deletion_protection = "false"
  enable_display      = "false"

  labels = {
    container-vm = "cos-stable-80-12739-91-0"
  }

  machine_type = "g1-small"

  metadata = {
    gce-container-declaration = "spec:\n  containers:\n    - name: instance-container\n      image: nginx\n      stdin: false\n      tty: false\n  restartPolicy: Always\n\n# This container declaration format is not public API and may change without notice. Please\n# use gcloud command-line tool or Google Cloud Console to run Containers on Google Compute Engine."
    google-logging-enabled    = "true"
  }

  name = "instance-container"

  network_interface {
    access_config {
      nat_ip       = "104.199.164.22"
      network_tier = "PREMIUM"
    }

    name               = "nic0"
    network            = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-id/global/networks/default"
    network_ip         = "10.140.15.223"
    subnetwork         = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-id/regions/asia-east1/subnetworks/default"
    subnetwork_project = "your-project-id"
  }

  project = "your-project-id"

  scheduling {
    automatic_restart   = "true"
    on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE"
    preemptible         = "false"
  }

  service_account {
    email  = "your-project-id-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"]
  }

  shielded_instance_config {
    enable_integrity_monitoring = "true"
    enable_secure_boot          = "false"
    enable_vtpm                 = "true"
  }

  zone = "asia-east1-b"
}
```

After comparing with normal instance resources, it looks like relies on the metadata `gce-container-declaration` and `labels` to do this job.

However, as the comments in the metadata said,

> This container declaration format is not public API and may change without notice.
>
> Please use gcloud command-line tool or Google Cloud Console to run Containers on Google Compute Engine.

It's more reliable to use gcloud command at this time before your [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/5832) be solved by Terraform Google Cloud Platform provider.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Terraform module](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm) that handles the generation of metadata for deploying containers on Google Compute Engine instances. It works similar to the command `gcloud compute instances create-with-container`.

You have to use the module along side with [google_compute_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance) resource and pass the attributes of the module to the resource, such as image, metadata and labels keys.

An example of usage.

```
# Module with metadata to create and start an instance with container. 
module "gce-container" {
  source = "terraform-google-modules/container-vm/google"
  version = "~> 2.0"  # Upgrade the version if necessary.

  container = {
    image = "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
  }
}

# Compute instance with container.
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "hello-app-instance"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  zone         = var.zone

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = module.gce-container.source_image
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.network
    # To be accesible from internet.
    access_config {
        # Ephemeral public IP.
    }
  }

  tags = ["container-vm-example"]

  metadata = {
    # Required metadata key.
    gce-container-declaration = module.gce-container.metadata_value
    google-logging-enabled    = "true"
    google-monitoring-enabled = "true"
  }

  labels = {
    # Required label key.
    container-vm = module.gce-container.vm_container_label
  }

  # A service account.
  service_account {
    email = var.service_account_email
    # List copied from default scope.
    # https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes#--scopes
    scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
    ]
  }
}
```

Some notes: unlike the command `gcloud compute instances create-with-container`, Terraform configuration will not add automatically

- An external IP address. In the example above I've used a network_interface.access_config to auto generate it.
- A default service account with default scope. In the example above I replicated the list of default scopes.